# Solr 3.5 Replication issue

Tags: solr, replication

I m facing issue with replicating slave from repeater in Solr.

The Replicatable index and the current index in slave are different. But still when I force replication, its not getting processed. What can probably be the issue?

I have the poll interval set at 10 min.

Can some one kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I did the following change to replicateconfig.xml. 
I tried configuring replicateAfter on startup

```
<str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
```